Is There any Untraceable Generalized Petersen Graph?
The Petersen graph is one of the example of  graph which is not Hamiltonian.
Can we find an example among the generalized Petersen graph which doesn't have Hamiltonian path (untraceable)?

Do you mean a Kneser graph, or do you have some other generalization of the Petersen graph in mind?

(There is one generalization of the Petersen graph that's specifically referred to as "the generalized Petersen graphs", but I'm kind of hoping you don't mean that one, because it is the worst of all the ways to generalize the Petersen graph.)

The generalized Petersen graph that I meant is this one : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_Petersen_graph

Unfortunate, but what can you do.

The graph $G(n,k)$ is defined to have:

Vertex set $\{u_0, u_1, \dots, u_{n-1}\} \cup \{v_0, v_1, \dots, v_{n-1}\}$.
Edge set $\{u_i u_{i+1} : 0 \le i \le n-1\} \cup \{u_i v_i : 0 \le i \le n-1\} \cup \{v_i v_{i+k} : 0 \le i \le n-1\}$, where the addition in "$i+1$" and "$i+k$" is done modulo $n$.

Let's define a few paths in this graph first. Let path $P(i)$ be the path starting at $u_i$ which goes from there to $v_i$, then $v_i$ to $v_{i-k}$ to $v_{i-2k}$ to $v_{i-3k}$ and so on until getting to $v_{i+k}$, then from there to $u_{i+k}$. (All addition and subtraction is modulo $n$.) Let path $Q(i)$ be the reverse of path $P(i+k)$: starting at $u_i$, it goes to $v_i$, then to $v_{i+k}, v_{i+2k}, v_{i+3k}, \dots$ until getting to $v_{i-k}$, and then from there to $u_{i-k}$.
If $n$ and $k$ have no common factors, then paths $P(i)$ and $Q(i)$ all end up going through all $n$ of the $v$-vertices $v_0, \dots, v_{n-1}$. In this case, we can find a Hamiltonian path in $G(n,k)$: start at $u_1$, go through the $u$-vertices to $u_2, u_3, \dots, u_k$, follow $Q(i)$ back to $u_0$, then go through the $u$-vertices $u_{n-1}, u_{n-2}, \dots, u_{k+1}$.
More generally, if $\gcd(n,k)=d$, then each path $P(i)$ and $Q(i)$ goes through only $n/d$ of the $v$-vertices: the vertices $v_j$ with $i \equiv j \pmod d$. So we can visit all of the $v$-vertices by a more complicated route:

Start at $u_0$ and follow $P(0)$ to $u_k$.
Go to $u_{k+1}$ and follow $Q(k+1)$ to $u_1$.
Go to $u_2$ and follow $P(2)$ to $u_{k+2}$.
Go to $u_{k+3}$ and follow $Q(k+3)$ to $u_3$.
And so on, until we've followed $d$ of the $P$- or $Q$-paths and seen all the $v$-vertices.

If $d$ is even, then this path ends by following $Q(k+d-1)$ to $u_{d-1}$; we've visited vertices $v_0, \dots, v_{n-1}$, as well as $u_0, \dots, u_{d-1}$ and $u_k, \dots, u_{k+d-1}$. Now, we can turn the path into a Hamiltonian path by continuing from $u_{d-1}$ to $u_d, u_{d+1}, u_{d+2}, \dots, u_{k-1}$, and also by adding the segment $u_{k+d}, u_{k+d+1}, \dots, u_n, u_0$ to the start.
If $d$ is odd, then instead the path ends by folowing $P(d-1)$ to $u_{k+d-1}$. By continuing from here to $u_{k+d}, u_{k+d+1}, \dots, u_n, u_0$, we get a cycle! Call this cycle $C$. It's not necessarily a Hamiltonian cycle; if $k>d$, then vertices $u_d, u_{d+1}, \dots, u_{k-1}$ are missing from $C$. But now, we can get a Hamiltonian path by starting with $u_d, u_{d+1}, \dots, u_{k-1}, u_k$, then following $C$ all the way around starting at $u_k$. (It's a cycle, so we can follow it all the way around from anywhere we like.
In all cases, we've found at least a Hamiltonian path in $G(n,k)$, so it is always traceable.

Hi, thank you for your answer. I haven't read all the argument carefully, but it is known that the usual Petersen graph is exactly $G(5,2)$ which is not Hamiltonian. So not all $G(n,k)$ is Hamiltonian. In that Wikipedia page, it is written that for certain choice of $n$ and $k$ they are at best hypohamiltonian (so not Hamiltonian).

Sorry, I meant to end by saying "at least a Hamiltonian path". Most of the time, this argument does not yield a Hamiltonian cycl.e

Ah ok, thanks! I will read your argument.
